# Razor pages model binding with and without model name

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have an ASP.NET 2.0 Razor page intended to implement a contact form. Here is part of the Contact.cshtml file:

```html
@page
@model ContactModel
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" asp-for="ContactMessageModel.Name" />
    <input type="email" asp-for="ContactMessageModel.Email" />
    <input type="text" asp-for="ContactMessageModel.Message" />
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<SiteKey>"></div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
</form>
```

Here is part of the Contact.cshtml.cs file:

```cs
public class ContactModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public ContactMessageModel ContactMessageModel { get; set; }

    public IActionResult OnPostAsync()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }

        return RedirectToPage("MessageSent");
    }
}

public class ContactMessageModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    [Required, BindProperty(name="g-recaptcha-response"]
    public string RecaptchaResponse { get; set; }
}
```

When the form is submitted, the following form data appears in the request:

```
ContactMessageModel.Name: Fractor
ContactMessageModel.Email: fractor@example.com
ContactMessageModel.Message: Hi there!
g-recaptcha-response: <recaptcha response data>
```

Because the dynamically created `g-recaptcha-response` form data name does not start with `ContactMessageModel`, only the Name, Email and Message properties are bound.

I have looked at using `[Bind(Prefix = "")]` but it looks like I can't apply this to (single) property in the class.

Is there a way of binding to all properties in this model class, despite the different prefixes?

Answer (score 0):

### Edit

You can create `a hidden control` in the view to bind `RecaptchaResponse`, and by triggering the robot's `data-callback` event, passing the response value to the hidden control in js.

```
    <form method="post">
        <input type="text" asp-for="ContactMessageModel.Name" />
        <input type="email" asp-for="ContactMessageModel.Email" />
        <input type="text" asp-for="ContactMessageModel.Message" />
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="your key" data-callback="ClickRobot"></div>
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="ContactMessageModel.RecaptchaResponse" />
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
    </form>

<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=en-US"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
<script>
    var ClickRobot = function () {
        var response = grecaptcha.getResponse();
        $("#ContactMessageModel_RecaptchaResponse").val(response);
    };
</script>
```

Contact :

```
 public class ContactModel : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty]
        public ContactMessageModel ContactMessageModel { get; set; }
        public IActionResult OnPostAsync()
        {  
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }

            return RedirectToPage("MessageSent");
        }
    }

    public class ContactMessageModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Message { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string RecaptchaResponse { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is the test process:

[image]

Comment: The form data can be bound to properties even if there is no corresponding element in the view. See the `SomeData` property in this post, this does get bound if a corresponding value exists in the form data. Just doesn't validate for some reason. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61465796/custom-validation-fires-if-in-model-class-but-not-on-page-property

Comment: @fractor, I modified my answer. You can use the `data-callback` event of g-recaptcha to get the return value of verification on the `client` side and bind it to the `RecaptchaResponse` field.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your effort in supplying information related to this question. However, we don't have an answer to the original question "Is there a way of binding to all properties in this model class, despite the different prefixes?".