# Custom validation fires if in model class but not on page property

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a contact Razor page implemented in ASP.NET Core 2.0. I am using model binding and custom validation.

If I use custom validation on a separate model class, the validation method is called. If I use custom validation on a property on the PageModel, the validation method is not called. However, all properties are successfully bound.

Here's the PageModel class and the separate model class:

```cs
public class ContactModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public ContactMessageModel ContactMessageModel { get; set; }

    [BindProperty, CustomValidation]
    public string SomeData { get; set; }

    public IActionResult OnPostAsync()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }

        return RedirectToPage("MessageSent");
    }
}

public class ContactMessageModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required, CustomValidation]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

A test validation attribute class is as follows:

```cs
public class CustomValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

The validation attribute is called for the `ContactMessageModel.Message` property, but it isn't called for `ContactModel.SomeData` property.

Why is this and how do I fix it?

Comment: I'm noticing the same thing.  @fractor - did you find any reason behind this, or a way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I was running into this too.  In my case my issue was because I missed the addition of the `[BindProperty]` attribute when I moved the properties from a wrapper class model into the `PageModel` directly.  I see that's not the case for you.

In your case I do see that you have the `[Required]` attribute on all properties except the `ContactModel.SomeData`.  Maybe adding `[Required]` there would get things acting as you would expect?